# W/System: A resource failed to call end. When using HttpsURLConnection - Android

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

In the logcat I get a warning:
**W/System: A resource failed to call end.**

I am 100% positive that this piece of code makes the warning, since when I take it out it stops.
I can't seem to fix it so it doesn't display warning.

The purpose of the  code is to check if there is internet connection or not.

It is on separate thread. Declared with:

```java
public class ConnectWifiThread extends Thread {
    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
```

**Here is the code:**

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
    HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    https.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
    https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    https.setConnectTimeout(2000); // mTimeout is in seconds
    https.connect();

    int tempResponse = https.getResponseCode();

    if (tempResponse == 200) {
        https.disconnect();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        https=null;
        url=null;

        Thread.sleep(50);
        Log.d("Has", "internet");
        return true;
    } else {
        https.disconnect();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        https=null;
        url=null;
        Thread.sleep(50);
        Log.d("NO", "internet");
        return false;
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Error checking internet", e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a URLConnection, by default it makes an input stream for you to read the response. You'd get that by calling `getInputStream()` on the connection, and then you'd read the stream to completion *and close it*.

If you don't need the data, you can alternatively call `setDoInput(false)` to save you the trouble of doing the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had this error and try to figure it out for several hours, until i simply ended the InputStream after reading it  " InputStream .close();"